# Magento2: Add Custom table next to Product attribute in Product Detail Page

Tags: magento2, custom-block, product-detail-page

How to add Custom table next to product attribute in a product detail page

[image]

Comment: What u want to show in the table?

Comment: @HafizArslan I need to show hard coded html tags

Answer (score 0):

Create a Block in Admin site (like:  **Identifier is 'table'**) add HTML tags what u want.
Create a file, name is **table.phtml**

> app/design/frontend/vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/table.phtml

```
<?php
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('table')->toHtml();
?>
```

Then call the file in **catalog_product_view.xml**

> app/design/frontend/vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="table"
             template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/table.phtml" >
        </block>
       <move element="table" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.stock.sku"/>
</page>
```

After that running these commands:

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
sudo php bin/magento cache:clean
sudo php bin/magento cache:flush
```